# Google Closure Source Map Not Connecting Source In Chrome

Tags: compiler-construction, maps, closures, google-closure

I'm using Google Closure to generate minified JS/source map and can't get the source map to connect the source to the minified script in the "Sources" window in Chrome.

Code taken from the [Google Closure compiler documentation](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app)

My source is this (hello.js):

```
// A simple function.
function hello(longName) {
alert('Hello, ' + longName);
}
hello('New User');
```

My compiler execution command is:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js hello.js --js_output_file hello.min.js --create_source_map hello.min.js.map
```

This executes successfully and produces:

Minified source (hello.min.js):

```
function hello(a){alert("Hello, "+a)}hello("New User");
```

I add the following line to the end of hello.min.js as recommended in [this article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/)

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=hello.min.js.map
```

Everything, source map included, is in the same directory and source maps are enabled in Chrome.  The index.html page simply includes hello.min.js in the body tag.

Can anyone see what I'm doing incorrectly?  I'd really appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of the source map?  Can you load the sources from the locations listed?

Comment: The source map lists ["hello.js"] as the value for the "sources" key and this file loads properly.

Comment: do you see the request HTTP request for the source map and is the proper content returned?

Comment: Ah - I don't see the request for it.  Is there an issue with my sourceMappingURL comment?  I've tried the URL every way I know.

Comment: Confused - this is working on another computer and I don't see a network call there for the file either.  Pretty stuck on this one.

Comment: firewall? or AV software?

Comment: That just might be it.  Hadn't thought about that.  Is there anywhere that Chrome would report the failed load?

Comment: I don't know about that.

Comment: Ok.  I think we'll try to rule that out before we explore this any further.  If you want to post the av/firewall issue as an answer, I'll mark it as solved.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to verify that you don't have an antivirus/security product or firewall blocking the request for the source map file.

Comment: I'm almost certain that this is the issue.  I don't manage the security on my machine/network so I can't test but I'd say this is it.  Thanks so much, John for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Also, note that the new comment pragma is now

```
//# sourceMappingURL=hello.min.js.map
```

instead of the old

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=hello.min.js.map
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to enable source map loading in the developer tools.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response and I apologize - I should have mentioned that the source maps are enabled.  Question is now updated.